# Calling all autologicians

Tags: logical-deduction, word, word-game

A word is autological if it describes itself. For example, *pentasyllabic* has five syllables and thus is autological.

A word is heterological if it does not describe itself. For example, *monosyllabic* has five syllables and thus is heterological.

**Puzzle:** Find

1. A word that cannot be either autological or heterological.
2. A word that can equally well be either autological or heterological.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

For 1:

> *Heterological*

because

> it describes itself iff it does not describe itself, so it is contradictory to call it either autological or heterological.

For 2:

> *Autological*

because

> it does not produce any contradictions, whether you call it autological or heterological.

Comment: So the answers are in the question itself.

Answer (score 7):

For number 2 I'd suggest

> Understood

because

> Depending on who reads it (English speaker or non English speaker) they will either understand it or not.

others in a similar vain

> readable, writable

Comment: the "similar vain" actually has autological words...